# Get path of Gemfile when Rails loading my gem via bundler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I've build a little rails development kit with development dependencies, generators and stuff for my personal use. I would like to be able to configure some things when loading the gem. An initializer is executed too late for gems like pry-rails.

So it would be cool to just use a configuration file in the project root. Though Rails is defined when my gem is loaded, Rails.root returns nil. How can I get the project root? It can be hackish and everything, it's just for some people.

This is my "initializer" which works great when absolutely addressing the config for one project:

```
class MyDevkit < MonkeyDevkit
  # =======
  # = Pry =
  # =======
  # disable pry components completely
  #disable :pry

  # do not make pry rails default console
  #disable :pry, :console

  # ========
  # = Mail =
  # ========
  # disable mail components completely
  #disable :mail

  # disable letter opener
  #disable :mail, :letter_opener

  # ========
  # = Misc =
  # ========
  #disable :rack_profiler
  #disable :better_errors
  #disable :quiet_assets

  # comment to (temporary) disable the devkit completely
  kitify!
end
```

Comment: May be this article can help you: http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/344833329/mygem-configure-block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you try using `Dir.getwd` to get current working directory (note: current working dir does not mean your gem's directory. it is a directory that ruby executable was called from), which should be same what you would get from Rails.root (unless some gem changes working dir)

Comment: Cool, this seems to work! Let's see if somebody can beat that ;-)

Comment: @2called-chaos so you want to know how to do it another way?